# How to Get Started with mixed_panel?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, tracking

I ran `gem install mixpanel-ruby`
I also added `mixpanel-ruby` in the gemfile.

I'm confused as to what to do next?

**initializers/mixed_panel.rb**

```
require 'mixpanel-ruby'

tracker = Mixpanel::Tracker.new(ENV['YOUR_MIXPANEL_TOKEN'])

user = User.find([:id])

# Track an event on behalf of user "User1"
tracker.track(user.id, 'A Mixpanel User')

# Send an update to User1's profile
tracker.people.set(user.id, {
    '$name' => user.name,
    '$last_name' => user.last_name,
})
```

I'm not sure if I put the above code in an initializer or application.rb or in the user model.

When I try to push the changes to heroku I get the error: `ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound: Couldn't find User with 'id'=id`.

I want to be able to track the behavior of each user.

**REFERENCE:** https://mixpanel.com/help/reference/ruby

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
I think you can do like: 
put `$tracker = Mixpanel::Tracker.new(ENV['YOUR_MIXPANEL_TOKEN'])` 
in initializers/mixed_panel.rb and on application controller you can put rest of your code with a after_filter and when current_user present or can put code on any action where you need to track and get find user there

def track_details
 # your code and use $tracker
end
```

Comment: Thank you. Okay so I did as you said. Sorry I forgot to ask in my question where I should put `require 'mixpanel-ruby'`. Should I put that in the initializer with `$tracker = Mixpanel::Tracker.new(ENV['YOUR_MIXPANEL_TOKEN'])`?

Comment: Yes put on initializer

Comment: Then I set `user = current_user.id`

Comment: Thank you! Got passed the `heroku push` error! But mixedpanel dashboard is giving the error `We have not received any data yet` upon clicking `Check` for the people setup page. I also added `mixpanel.identify(user.id);` to `track_detatils`

Comment: you called track_details after an action perform from frontend ?

Answer (score 0):

General idea is that when a user performs some actoion, you track it. 
There is no one right way to do it. If its done uisng their JS library, you would put the code in the view layer.

but since you are doing it in the server side, the logical place to put the code is in the controllers .

Ex :
 when a user likes a post, you put the tracking code in the controller action thats appropriate . you would need the user object to pass on the user id, and any other details you want to share with mixpanel.

Obviously , I am not saying that controllers are the only place where you would put the tracking code, in some cases , you would use a Task Runner, Que to delegate it in the background .

Comment: Thank you. That gave me a clearer idea on the ultimate goal, but I don't know how to fix the error to finish integrating mixpanel.